# All hikaricp connection are in use

Tags: slick, hikaricp

- hikaricp: 2.3.7
- mysql-connector-j: 5.1.30
- slick: 3.1.0

HikariCP Config

```
autoCommit......................true
catalog.........................
connectionCustomizer............com.zaxxer.hikari.AbstractHikariConfig$1@37b70343
connectionCustomizerClassName...
connectionInitSql...............
connectionTestQuery.............
connectionTimeout...............30000
dataSource......................
dataSourceClassName.............
dataSourceJNDI..................
dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
driverClassName.................com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
healthCheckProperties...........{}
healthCheckRegistry.............
idleTimeout.....................600000
initializationFailFast..........true
isolateInternalQueries..........false
jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:mysql://10.66.108.202/weixin_prod
leakDetectionThreshold..........0
maxLifetime.....................1800000
maximumPoolSize.................10
metricRegistry..................
minimumIdle.....................10
password........................<masked>
poolName........................HikariPool-0
readOnly........................false
registerMbeans..................false
threadFactory...................
transactionIsolation............
username........................weixin_prod
validationTimeout...............5000
HikariCP pool HikariPool-0 configuration:
allowPoolSuspension.............false
autoCommit......................true
catalog.........................
connectionCustomizer............com.zaxxer.hikari.AbstractHikariConfig$1@37b70343
connectionCustomizerClassName...
connectionInitSql...............
connectionTestQuery.............
connectionTimeout...............30000
dataSource......................
dataSourceClassName.............
dataSourceJNDI..................
dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
driverClassName.................com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
healthCheckProperties...........{}
healthCheckRegistry.............
vaidleTimeout.....................600000
```

Logs

```
    2015-10-23 10:25:21 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0) - Before cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=0, avail=10, waiting=0) 
    2015-10-23 10:25:21 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0) - After cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=0, avail=10, waiting=0) 
    2015-10-23 10:25:51 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0) - Before cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=10, avail=0, waiting=0) 
    2015-10-23 10:25:51 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0) - After cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=10, avail=0, waiting=0) 
    2015-10-23 10:25:51 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in HikariCP connection filler (pool HikariPool-0) - After fill pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=10, avail=0, waiting=0) 
    2015-10-23 10:26:21 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0) - Before cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=10, avail=0, waiting=10) 
    2015-10-23 10:26:21 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0) - After cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=10, avail=0, waiting=10) 
    2015-10-23 10:26:21 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in HikariCP connection filler (pool HikariPool-0) - After fill pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=10, avail=0, waiting=10) 
    2015-10-23 10:26:21 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in slick-async-executor-3 - Timeout failure pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=10, avail=0, waiting=9) 
    2015-10-23 10:26:21 +0800 [DEBUG] from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in slick-async-executor-8 - Timeout failure pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=10, avail=0, waiting=9)
```

[view detail log](https://gist.github.com/jilen/f4edf44f4013ffe7a1eb)

All connections are in use after `2015-10-23 10:26:21` and then all operations are waiting and timeout util restart the whole app ?

> What's wrong ?

Comment: What is the value of maximumPoolSize config? And are you sure that you are closing a connection when you are done with it?

Comment: @ovunccetin I've put the config info. And slick actually auto release connection.

Comment: I've heard reported that slick can consume higher than the default 10 connections in the pool at its peak.  Try a maximumPoolSize of 20.

Comment: @brettw I've set it to 64 and no luck

Comment: If not that, then probably better to ask over in the slick google group.

Comment: @jilen It would be interesting to know how did you fix the issue. Could you please post the solution what fixed it.

Comment: @Shepherd I solved it by get ride of slick and copy a [queue](https://gist.github.com/jilen/718d245bd095c9ad79f9ac6893df6623) from somewhere.